# CSS files not being linked

Tags: html, css

I am facing a strange issue, Below are the steps to reproduce it

> 1. Close all instances of a browser (any) and then run the below link, notice that the styles don't get applied.
>
> https://libenc.iaea.org/iii/encore/home?lang=eng&suite=def&advancedSearch=true&searchString=
>
> 2. Go to this link in adjacent tab - https://libenc.iaea.org/iii/encore/?lang=eng
> 3. Now,  refresh the page with the first link, the styles gets applied.

If you compare the page source at **stage 1**. and **stage 3**., you can notice that the source in 3. contains these additional includes

What is causing this to happen? Is there any way to have these styles included while at stage 1.?

I don't have access to modify these pages since its hosted by another vendor.

**UPDATE:**
Below is almost exactly similar link from another user of the same vendor which works perfectly.

http://encore.lipscomb.edu/iii/encore/home?lang=eng&suite=cobalt&advancedSearch=true&searchString=

Comment: Is your `/home` serving the same page as `/` - sometimes they serve different pages which may account for the missing stylesheets on one of them. Although having just been to the page, there seems to be some sort of redirection so it looks as if first time you load the page it's meant to apply some sort of session var which probably selects the stylesheet.  However, this is all a guess as you have provided no code

Comment: @Pete: I believe the pages are same, since this works the same as in stage 2 - https://libenc.iaea.org/iii/encore/home?lang=eng. The contents are somehow dynamically generated

Comment: ps Surely you need to contact the vendor to ask these questions

Comment: This is a similar link from another user of the same vendor which seems to work well - http://encore.lipscomb.edu/iii/encore/home?lang=eng&suite=cobalt&advancedSearch=true&searchString=

Comment: No, the 'suite' has been configured as 'def' in our case

Comment: **What is causing this to happen?** - without information about code or how its being served there is no real way to know. **Is there any way to have these styles included while at stage 1.?** - yes absolutely - contact the vendor.